# Prove the Result is 1/2

Tags: summation, induction

Given a natural number $n>1$, add up all the fractions $\dfrac{1}{pq}$ , where $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime,
$0< p <   q \le n$, and $p+q>n$. Prove that the result is always $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

*What I Know:*

1. The proof itself was done using induction.

*What I Don't Know*

1. I honestly have no idea how to write the proof to this problem.

**Can somebody please help me?**

Comment: If I consider n=6,can I consider  (1,6) as a suitable (p,q) set?What I mean to say is that do you consider 1 and any other number as relatively prime?

Comment: @tatan: For $n=2$, we have $(p=1,q=2)$. For $n=3$, we have $(p=1,q=3),(p=2,q=3)$. For $n=4$, we have $(p=1,q=4),(p=2,q=3),(p=3,q=4)$. For $n=5$, we have $(p=1,q=5),(p=2,q=5),(p=3,q=4),(p=3,q=5),(p=4,q=5)$. For $n=6$, we have $(p=1,q=6),(p=5,q=6),(p=2,q=5),(p=3,q=4),(p=3,q=5),(p=4,q=5)$. This seems to work out fine.

Answer (score 1):

Put $A_n=\{(p,q); 1\leq p<q\leq n, p\wedge q=1,p+q\geq n+1\}$

Then $A_{n+1}$ is different of $A_n$ in only two ways:

1) if $(p,q)$ is in $A_n$ and $p+q=n+1$, then $(p,q)$ is not in $A_{n+1}$ (let $B_n$ this set). Otherwise, $(p,q)$ is in $A_{n+1}$.

2) The elements $(p,n+1)$ with $p$ prime to $n+1$ are in $A_{n+1}$, but not in $A_n$.Otherwise, an element of $A_{n+1}$ is in $A_n$. Hence, the difference between the sum over $A_n$ and $A_{n+1}$ is 
 $$-\sum_{(p,q)\in B_n}\frac{1}{pq}+\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{p\wedge(n+1)=1}\frac{1}{p}$$

Now as $\frac{1}{p(n+1-p)}=\frac{1}{n+1}(\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{n+1-p})$,  the sum over $B_n$, is equal to

$$\frac{1}{n+1}(\sum\frac{1}{p}+\sum\frac{1}{n+1-p})$$
 where the  sum is over the $p$ with $1\leq p<\frac{n+1}{2}$,$p$ prime to $n+1$ and we see that this is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{p\wedge(n+1)=1}\frac{1}{p}$, and we are done.